# Why do lots of people use "seperate" instead of "separate"?

Tags: etymology, errors

- Catalan: "separar"
- English: "separate"
- French: "séparer"
- Galician: "separar"
- Italian: "separare"
- Latin: "separo"
- Portuguese: "separar"
- Romanian: "separa"
- Spanish: "separar"
- Sweedish: "separera"

Then, why do I see "seperate" lots of times? Where does it come etymologically? Will it become accepted?

Comment: People are just careless or ignorant. Nothing more. They don’t understand the etymology. It’s the #1 most misspelled word in the English language. *Occurrence* comes in second.

Comment: *Seperate* may be phonetically closer to the way most people pronounce it (at least, people who pronounce it with three syllables), as with *definately*, *calender*, *independant*, *allegience*, and many others.

Comment: I think one of the reasons is the lack of parallelism with _desperate_. If you know the etymology, you will understand why the two words do not follow the same pattern, but the sound pattern is the same, so people expect the spelling to be the same.

Comment: @choster: For me, the second syllable of *calender, independant* is ***I** as in **him***, but I never have to stop and think if I'm spelling those correctly. My second syllable in *separate* is ***er** as in **her***, so I always have remind myself about connections with *apart, paring* or I'm likely to get that one wrong.

Comment: English speakers have learned that unstressed vowels (especially before a resonant) are always centralized and reduced, and that it doesn't make any difference how they are spelled. In other words, English has lost the difference between unstressed /er/ and unstressed /ar/ -- both become /ər/. So there's no reason why an English reader would remember to spell an unstressed /ər/ as AR, instead of ER (which is the most common English spelling of /ər/).

Comment: Why? Because English doesn't always spell things the way they sound. So it is easy to make spelling mistakes.

Comment: @Mitch `s/always/ever/`; that is, **English *never* spells things “as they sound”** — the very notion makes no sense! Depending on local dialect, we’ve like 40–48 **phonemes** in English: things you can find minimal pairs for. Now multiply those 40-odd phonemes by some smallish real number above 1.0 to account for the various **phonetic allophones** (“phones”) each phoneme can take on, again varying by region, register, and speaker. With barely 26 undiacriticked letters left in the modern English alphabet, these ***many-to-many-to-many* mappings** render any spell-by-sound idea sheer nonsense.

Comment: You really answered your own question right there. English speakers are not generally fluent in French, Latin, Catalan, Galician, Romanian, and Portuguese. English speakers also don't assume that the spelling in English must correspond to the one in French. That's because it really doesn't have to. This is English, not Catalan. We could choose to spell *separate* as *supperheighde*. Or as *Susan*. By the way, why did you just write *Sweedish*? The *ee* should be an *e*, the *w* should be a *v*, and the *dish* should be a *nska*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe people base spelling more on sound than on etymology, though this is rather unreliable as the connection between the spelling of English and the sound of English is extremely weak. The  ⁄ ər ⁄  sound is commonly spelled as "er", so that is likely their basis for spelling *separate* as "sep‑er‑ate."